# Outlook: how to set up the reply template with header image?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007 I use a design template for my signature for sending email (called Miguel Ángel in the screengrab), I use a header image and everything works perfectly.
I want the same design for replying, but the template does not apply, this is a normal behaviour, it is said.

So the solution I found was to create another signature (Miguel Ángel respuesta) and use the editor, insert the image on top of the message.

It works but it's always less wide than the original and it is blurry. The image has 96dpi as this is one of the possible problems the image can have, but even if I put any resolution and less kilobytes I continue to have the same problem: the image is smaller.

How can I preserve the quality and width?
Any other solution for replying with the same format? 
Here is a screengrab of the configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the workaround, and it is unbelievable.

You have to create a new email, copy your template and go to configuration, you select the signature you are using and paste this in your editor.

This way you don't have problems of quality or width.

Just amazed how shabby this is.